# How to calculate total price for input using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a formset of inputs, I have quantity and price inputs and I want to calculate the total using jQuery for every row?

```js
$('#step2').on("click", function() {
  var total = 0;
  $('.na qu').each(function() {
    var prix = Number($('.na').val());
    var quantite = Number($('.qu').val());
    var total = prix * quantite
    console.log(total)
  });
  alert(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite">

  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite">

  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite">

  <button id="step2" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter1</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I pasted your code into a snippet and the following error pops up, `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '+='"`. Also, you don't do anything from stopping your form from being submitted and reloading the page. Oh and IDs **must** be unique

Comment: I edited the code, but I have no errors in my console

Comment: Another thing to note is that your jquery selector is $('.na qu') which will never work as  without a preceding . you are asking jQuery to look for a tag name so <qu>. You'll need to change this to  $('.na , .qu')

Comment: So add `total` to the `totalPoints` .....

Comment: the total is always 0 , what i am missing ?

Comment: See my answer. You weren't adding the total of `each` to the totalPoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide the result you want.

```js
$('#step2').on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var total = 0;

  $('.qu').each(function(index) {
    var quantiteVal = $(this).val();

    // get the prix element with the same index as this quantite element
    var $prixEl = $('.na').eq(index);
    var prixVal = $prixEl.val();

    // ensure values aren't empty, undefined, or not a number
    var quantite = quantiteVal && !isNaN(quantite) ? parseInt(quantiteVal) : 0;
    var prix = prixVal && !isNaN(prix) ? parseInt(prixVal) : 0;

    total += quantite * prix;
  });

  alert(total);
});
```

Comment: the result is Nan ??

Comment: Did you input the numbers?

Comment: Code has been updated. so, checking alphabet or empty string.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you'll want to fix:

#### You have three pairs of form inputs, but their names and ids are duplicated.

Here's an example of what it would look like with unique names and ids:

```html
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire-0" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire-0">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite-0" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite-0">

  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire-1" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire-1">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite-1" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite-1">

  <input type="text" name="form-0-Prix_Unitaire-2" class="na" id="id_form-0-Prix_Unitaire-2">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-Quantite-2" class="qu" id="id_form-0-Quantite-2">
```

This doesn't directly affect your price*quantity calculation, but will cause you problems when submitting your form if not corrected.